# how to show the next month using concat, month 12 (dec) following month became 13

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table like this.

| employee_id | join_year | join_month | joindatetime | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011 | 03 | 2011-03-06 06:00:00 | Mike | Jordan |
| 2 | 2012 | 11 | 2012-11-19 07:00:00 | John | Simpson |
| 31 | 2019 | 12 | 2019-12-05 11:30:00 | Jane | Athur |

and I need to add a column using concat a couple of columns and
one special requirement is that join_month is to show the following month.

For example,
join_month is 03 (for Mike) + 1 (adding 1 to get the following month) so outcome should be 04.
and if join_month is 11 + 1 (following month) so outcome should be 12

so the expected outcome should be

```
1-20110401-Mike-Jordan
2-20121201-John-Simpson
31-20200101-Jane-Athur
```

so with my limited knowledge, I used the following method

```
concat(employee_id,'-',join_year,join_month+1,'01','-',firstname,'-',lastname) as 'WWID'
```

however, I am getting the following result.

```
1-2011401-Mike-Jordan
2-20121201-John-Simpson
31-20191301-Jane-Athur
```

2 issues here.

1st issue : 2 digits of month is becoming 1 digit for the first line (04 > 4)

2nd issue : following month of 201912 (dec) should be following year of 202001 (jan) but it comes out as 201913 instead..

is there any way to achieve above expeced outcome? Pleae help.

Thank you

Comment: Use date data types for date arithmetic.

Comment: Why do you need `join_year` and `join_month` when you already have `joindatetime`?

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> select extract(year_month from date_add('2019-12-05', interval 1 month)) as ym;
+--------+
| ym     |
+--------+
| 202001 |
+--------+
```

Comment: great Answer. You can also remove the date_add function. a + before the INTERVAL is also working: **select extract(year_month from '2019-12-05' + interval 1 month) as ym;**

Comment: Yes, it's optional. Using `DATE_ADD()` works too, and some people find it is easier to read the code.

Comment: yes this is much more readable but I'm always looking for ways to keep it easier for the optimizer as it makes it easier to interpret

Comment: @BerndBuffen Neither are easier for the parser, and would count as premature optimisation anyway (or, at least, focusing time and effort in the wrong places)...

Comment: You are absolutely right, only if you get used to this notation does it easily appear in WHERE.
I didn't want to find fault with her answer at all. My first thought when I read the question was essential! worse and I liked hers straight away

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH tbl (employee_id, join_year, join_month, joindatetime, first_name, last_name) AS (
    VALUES
        ROW( 1, 2011, 03, '2011-03-06 06:00:00', 'Mike', 'Jordan'),
        ROW( 2, 2012, 11, '2012-11-19 07:00:00', 'John', 'Simpson'),
        ROW(31, 2019, 12, '2019-12-05 11:30:00', 'Jane', 'Athur')
)
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', employee_id, DATE_FORMAT(joindatetime + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y%m01'), first_name, last_name) AS WWID
FROM tbl;
```

Outputs:

| WWID |
| --- |
| 1-20110401-Mike-Jordan |
| 2-20121201-John-Simpson |
| 31-20200101-Jane-Athur |

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the special case when the month is 12. The month number wraps around to 1, and the year has to increment. You can use `IF` or `CASE` for this.

```
concat(employee_id,'-',
    IF(join_month = 12, join_year+1, join_year),
    IF(join_month = 12, 1, join_month+1),
    '01','-',firstname,'-',lastname) as 'WWID'
```

Comment: Or, just use date datatypes for date arithmetic?  No special cases means no boundary condition coding errors.